# str_sub returning NA with ifelse

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I'm attempting to remove the last letter in a data frame if it matches 'Z' or 'Q'.

The data frame:

```
PlayerName    Score
'JohnQ'         75
'Robert'        80
'AlbertZ'       67
'JeffQ'         88
```

Code:

## Remove 'Z' or 'Q' if last letter of string

```
data <- data %>% mutate(PlayerName = ifelse(stri_sub(data$PlayerName, -1) == 'Q'|
                                                stri_sub(data$PlayerName, -1) == 'Z', 
                                                str_sub(data$PlayerName, end=-2), 
                                                data$PlayerName))
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
PlayerName    Score
'NA'          75
'Robert'      80
'NA'          67
'NA'          88
```

No idea why this is happening, I the code `str_sub(data$PlayerName, end=-2)` returns the correct information when I use it outside of the `ifelse` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not base R `sub` with the appropriate [regex](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)?

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data %>% mutate(PlayerName = sub("Z$|Q$", "", PlayerName))
data
#  PlayerName Score
#1       John    75
#2     Robert    80
#3     Albert    67
#4       Jeff    88
```

Explanation: the character `$` marks the end of the string and `|` separates alternative patterns. Therefore `"Z$|Q$"` matches either `"Z"` or `"Q"` at the end of the string.

Comment: Nice idea. 1 question, Can it be expanded to remove last 2 letters, If the last is either Z or Q? (Not sure If OP needs just the last removed)

Comment: @Sotos YOu can just specify the `.` i.e. `df %>% mutate(PlayerName =  sub(".(Z|Q)$", "", PlayerName))`

Comment: Simple as that!! Thanks @akrun

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the `stri_sub(..., -2)`. You need to specify from character 1 until -2 characters, i.e.

```
library(stringi)

with(df, ifelse(stri_sub(PlayerName, -1, -1) %in% c('Q', 'Z'), 
                          stri_sub(PlayerName,  1, nchar(PlayerName)-2), PlayerName))

#[1] "Joh"    "Robert" "Alber"  "Jef"
```

**DATA**

```
structure(list(PlayerName = c("JohnQ", "Robert", "AlbertZ", "JeffQ"
), Score = c(75L, 80L, 67L, 88L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, as well in `base R`, using `endsWith` and `substr`

```
index <- which(endsWith(df$PlayerName, 'Q') | endsWith(df$PlayerName, 'Z'))
df$PlayerName[index] <- substr(df$PlayerName[index], 
                             rep(1, length(index)), 
                             nchar(df$PlayerName[index])-1L)
df
#   PlayerName Score
# 1       John    75
# 2     Robert    80
# 3     Albert    67
# 4       Jeff    88
```

Answer (score 2):

Or even simpler:

```
library(roperators)

df %>% mutate(PlayerName = PlayerName %-% "Z$|Q$")
```